# Can the 'Make the focus rectangle thicker' system option be set automatically in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, accessibility, control-panel, focus

I found out that the 'Make the focus rectangle thicker' system option is set on two computers under control of Windows 10 while developing my software for this OS (technical details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64228376/drawfocusrect-function-strange-2-pixel-focus-rectangle-in-windows-10)). This option is hidden deep inside the Windows settings in the classic Control Panel in this section: `Ease of Access` > `Ease of Access Center` > `Make the computer easier to see`:

[image]

The strange thing is that I definitely know that I did not set this option myself. It seems, this option can be set automatically by Windows. One of my assumptions why this happened is that one of those computers is an ASUS laptop with high-res screen. However, this is not true for the second pc in a system case - I never attached a high-res screen to it.

My question is: can Windows set the 'Make the focus rectangle thicker' option automatically in some specific situations (for example, if it finds a high-resolution screen)? Can it be related to turning on some accessibility options and tools like Windows Magnifier, Narrator and the like?

Comment: I did not find any Microsoft official document talking about whether this feature can be set automatically by windows. You might try to turn on some tools by yourself and then narrow down it.